# Run a C program to read a text file in terminal

Tags: c, file, terminal

I am a beginner of C programming. I am doing an assignment that requires me to use write a command with a C file and a .txt file as input in the terminal in MACOS, and read the content of the file using the C program, like "./cfile text.txt".

Do I have to include something like:

```
FILE *ptr = fopen("text.txt", "r");
```

in the C file?

If not, how can I get the "text.txt" file as the input to the C file?

Comment: Is there not already lots of information available on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use argc and argv. Execute your program in the shell writing "./program text.txt" and it'll work. Then you only have to write

```
int main(int argc, int *argv[])
{
      FILE *ptr;
      //rest of variables
      if (argc != 2) write(1, "Did not put a file name to read.\n", strln("Did not put a file name to read.\n"));
      ptr = fopen(argv[1], "r");
      //rest of program
}
```

Comment: I copied your code and I cannot compile the program successfully. I was asked to use "gcc cfile.c -o xxx" to compile, but the terminal showed  ``` "passing argument to parameter '__filename' here FILE   *fopen(const char *_restrict __filename, const char * ++restri...".``` How can I fix this problem? Thank you.